# PostgreSQL - how to convert string to date with universal format

Tags: postgresql, date

Is there universal way to convert a string to date in PostgreSQL if you don’t know the string format in advance?

For example: the string date may be in yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm-yyyy format or something else.

Thanks!

Comment: "*if you don’t know the string format in advance*" no. The only way is to test various formats and see which one succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typecasting the string to timestamp and then date. 
Something like:

select '2010-01-01 12:00:00'::timestamp::date

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal parameter to handle any date format. You have the [DateStyle parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT2-TABLE) and 
and the [date/time interpretation rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datetime-input-rules.html).